# Get current selection in Mozilla extension

Tags: firefox-addon, selection

For a Mozilla extension I want to get raw text (HTML removed) from any removed text.
If I use

```
var selectedText = content.getSelection().toString();
alert(selectedText);
```

within my method it works for selected text on HTML but not for text from forms (e.g. textarea). In this case, it returns nothing. Is there a way which works for all possible types of marked texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check `document.activeElement` and if it's an input or textarea, get the selection from it, otherwise fall back to `window.getSelection()`. I don't know how you access the `document` object from a Mozilla extension, but I'm sure you do.

Maybe something like this (passing in the page's `window` and `document` objects as function parameters):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/69uGL/

Code:

```
function getSelectedText(win, doc) {
    var activeEl = doc.activeElement, start, end;
    if (    activeEl &&
            /^(textarea|input)$/i.test(activeEl.nodeName) &&
            (start = activeEl.selectionStart) != (end = activeEl.selectionEnd)) {
        return activeEl.value.slice(start, end);
    } else {
        return "" + win.getSelection();
    }
}
```